# Why am I logged in as a different user using NTLM?

Tags: iis-6, windows-authentication, ntlm

This question is related to: [Windows authentication does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484121/windows-authentication-does-not-work)

I am developing a .NET 4.0 MVC3 application that has Integrated Windows Authentication turned on. If I open my application from my development machine (I am logged in as DOMAIN\USER) I am logged in automatically as DOMAIN\SERVERADMINACCOUNT. From any other machine on the network everything works as expected (current user is logged in automatically using NTLM).

Does anyone have an idea what's happening? The server is Windows 2003 with IIS6. All clients machines are Windows XP with SP3 or Windows 7 (mine is XP).

Comment: Do you have any credentials for that host in Control Panel -> Credential Manager?

Comment: No, only my domain account and two local accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer!

In `Control Panel` -> `User Account`s -> `Advanced` tab I clicked `Manage passwords` button and removed the configuration for the domain I used. Now I am logged in to my web application as a currently logged in Windows user.